# In C# I need to change the order of the forms I made

Tags: c#, windows

I need to change the order of the forms I made like for example get the login page first and the main cp next etc.(At the moment the the main cpcomes first and login form is last) What coding should I use and where?

Answer (score 0):

They are arranged alphabatically. You can arrange them accordingly by changing formname as that will not change class name and hence will not affect your project.

Answer (score 0):

The files in the Solution Explorer are ordered by file name.

You could rename the files (and keep the class names) by prefixing them with left zero  padded numbers: `0001_Login`.